# Cannot convert json object to struct

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I want to convert the json form the following url to the struct. But, I am getting the error `Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' to 'NSData'`

Here is the url for sample json data `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

Here is the struct

```
struct GetHelp: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var userId: Int
    var title: String
    var body: String
}
```

Here is the server communication

```
AF.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
       .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case let .success(value):

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let model = try decoder.decode([GetHelp].self, from: value as! Data)
                    print(model)
                } catch let parsingError {
                    print("Error", parsingError)
            }

            case let .failure(error): print(error)
        }

    }
```

Also, if you remove `value as! Data` then the following error will occur.

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'Data'
```

What is the reason I am getting the error and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass `.responseData` rather than `.responseJSON` to get the raw data, `.responseJSON` returns a collection type.

```
AF.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
       .responseData { response in

        switch response.result {
            case let .success(value):

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let model = try decoder.decode([GetHelp].self, from: value)
                    print(model)
                } catch {
                    print("Error", error)
            }

            case let .failure(error): print(error)
        }

    }
```

To use the array of dictionaries with `.responseJSON` you have to map the array to your model in code

```
AF.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
       .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case let .success(value):
                if let array = value as? [[String:Any]] {

                   let model = array.map { GetHelp(id: $0["id"] as! Int,                  
                                                   userId: $0["userId"] as! Int,
                                                   title: $0["title"] as! String,
                                                   body: $0["body"] as! String)}
                   print(model)   
                }

            case let .failure(error): print(error)
       }    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. But, I am expecting JSON from the response. Then why not responseJSON?

Comment: You are expecting JSON, but the returned object is an array of dictionaries and `JSONDecoder` expects raw data. Of course you can use the returned array but then you have to map the dictionaries to your model *manually* and drop `JSONDecoder`.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly take the data from the response even when you use a responseJSON block

```
request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
       .responseJSON { response in

        switch response.result {
            case let .success(value):

                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    if let data = response.data {
                       let model = try decoder.decode([GetHelp].self, from: data)
                       print(model)
                   }
                } catch let parsingError {
                    print("Error", parsingError)
            }

            case let .failure(error): print(error)
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to manually process `Decodable` responses in Alamofire 5, you can now do it directly:

```
AF.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
       .responseDecodable(of: GetHelp.self) { response in
            switch response.result {
            case let .success(value): print(value)
            case let .failure(error): print(error)
            }
        }
```